# Any third party template for developing kentico webpart

Tags: kentico

I want to know whether there any third party templates which we can use to develop parts or widgets in Kentico?
Something similar to Christoc's Module and Theme Development Template for DotNetNuke.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any templates for v8 or v9 any longer but you can easily create your own if you'd like.  I had provided some updates for v8 to work in VS 2012/2013 but it was decided they were no longer going to create/use them.  You could create them and post them in NuGet if you'd like.  I don't believe the Marketplace is accepting them as submissions but you could try.

Comment: thanks , i am seriously thinking for template ,so can minimize developers work

Comment: I simply create a new ascx control and then just set the inheritance and add the few other methods in it.  It's pretty quick and easy really.

Answer (score 1):

http://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/visual-studio/visual-studio-templates

This is for Kentico 7, but this is the only thing I know of.

Comment: surelly i go through this ,and try to search something for kentico 9 and kentico 8